# Why should we specify the const qualifier explicitly if we define conversion function?

Tags: c++

In the example:

```
struct A{ };

struct B
{
    B(){ };
    operator A(){ return A(); }
};

const B b;

void foo(A){ };

int main(){ foo(b); } //error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed14e1b9fc7bee93)**

compiler throws an error. But what the Standard says is (section `13.3.3.1.2/1 [over.ics.user]`):

> A user-defined conversion sequence consists of an initial standard
>   conversion sequence followed by a userdefined conversion (12.3)
>   followed by a second standard conversion sequence. [...]
>   If the user-defined conversion is specified by a conversion function
>   (12.3.2), the initial standard conversion sequence converts the source
>   type to the implicit object parameter of the conversion function.

Therefore in the example the first standar conversion should conver `const B` to `B` and then call the conversion function. But it didn't, why? How does it exactly work? Note the example will work fine if we replace `operator A(){ return A(); }` with `operator A() const{ return A(); }`

Comment: there is no standard conversion function to convert from const to non-const, the standard conversion is from non-const to const

Comment: @gsf Why don't you post your comment as an answer? It looks correct.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You do not demand a conversion sequence here, like the one you picked from the standard.

You are invoking

```
B::operator A()
```

on an object declared as "const B".

Actually, 3.9.1 says:

> A non-static member function may be declared const, volatile, or const
>   volatile. These cv-qualifiers affect the type of the this pointer
>   (9.3.2). They also affect the function type (8.3.5) of the member
>   function; a member function declared const is a const member function

Moreover 9.3.2/3:

> A cv-qualified member function can be called on an object-expression
>   (5.2.5) only if the object-expression is as cv-qualified or
>   less-cv-qualified than the member function.

As with any other method invocation, you are running into non-const method invocation on a const object. That protection is not broken for obvious reasons.

BTW, it seems that you answered the question yourself. Otherwise, hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, exactly! I'll add the reference to the Standard.